# How to customize the file name or get the file name of the saved mp4 file under video output folder of a specific test using selenium grid extras

Tags: selenium-grid

Enabled video in the selenium grid extras config json file and able to see mp4 videos saved under video output folder.

How do I get the saved mp4 file name of a test programatically ?

Also, is it possible customize the file name to give it a meaningful name like testname_dateofexecution ?

Answer (score 0):

RemoteWebdriver has a method GetCapabilities. Capability 'webdriver.remote.sessionId' returns the session id which is the file name of the mp4 file created in video output folder